# Append is duplicating the content

Tags: javascript, jquery, duplicates, append

I am trying to append content into my code. When I press a button my jQuery executes again and it appends once again. So my question is, is there a way to make sure the code only executes once? Or if there's a way to only do append once?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var uspar = '<div id="usparDiv"><img src="https://example.com"><ul><li>list 1</li><li>list 2</li><li>list 3</li></ul></div>';
  $('.extend-guarantee').append(uspar); 
});



<form class="extend-guarantee">
  <span class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="opt-name">Testing checkbox</span>
    <span class="icon-click"></span>
  </span>
```

Comment: It would be helpful to also see your HTML and the button click handler

Comment: There is no indication that the content are appending on a click event? This code runs initially (just once)? None the less, we need more context

Comment: JQuery executes only once on page load. Probably you have included this script twice in your HTML or smth like that.

Comment: @Endless was that to me? If so, the OP states `When I press a button my jQuery executes again...`

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you can try something like this.

In the code below, you create a function called appendToDom. You call it when a button is clicked and it appends a div with an id of usparDiv and all it's content (as defined in the function) to the DOM (in this case, the content is appended to the main element, as specified in appendToDom).

The appendToDom function can also check to make sure that the content is added only once (by checking if a div with an id of usparDiv exists). If it does, it returns and ends execution. If it does not, it appends the div to the DOM.

https://jsfiddle.net/eulloa/2a3ee3te/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').on('click', appendToDom)
});

function appendToDom() {
  if ($('#usparDiv').length)
    return;

    var uspar = '<div id="usparDiv"><img src="https://example.com"><ul><li>list 1</li><li>list 2</li><li>list 3</li></ul></div>';
  $('main').append(uspar);
}
```

Your current jQuery code will only execute this once because it's defined when the DOM is ready to go (document.ready). This way, your append logic will work when a button is clicked, not just when the DOM is ready.